# Inline-flex not working on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have an nav bar on my site (http://nerdherdgames.com/) that does not want to work on mobile browsers (iOS and Windows Phone). I believe has something to do with the CSS I have on the ul and and li tags. I'm using `Display: -webkit-inline-flex` on both of those tags. Was inline-flex deprecated in CSS3 by any chance? Any help is always appreciated!

-Rock

**Update:**
I am attempting to use a media query for devices with a width less that X and using inline-table on those.

**Update:**
`float: left;` is what I ended up going with. **Loki Chandu** answered it before updated it so, technically is answer is the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: This may be useful: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/ " -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}" may be needed in your responsive css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float:left;
```

works fine in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the CSS to use `display: block;` and `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `display: -webkit-inline-flex` did the trick for IOS devices (tested on 7.1.1 and 8.4)